# Read data sent by knockout by POST

Tags: javascript, java, knockout.js

I am trying to send data from a form and add it to an array on a server side. Data in alert is fine, but serverside array stays empty. Any suggesions?

Code responsible for sending post request:

```
var data = ko.toJSON("name : "+this.name())
alert(data);

$.post("/data", data, function(response) 
{        
})
```

Server code:

```
post("/data", (req, res) -> {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
    String name= req.queryParams("name");
    names.add(name);
    System.out.println(names.toString());

    model.put("template", "templates/profile.vtl");             

    return new ModelAndView(model, layout);

} , new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

Comment: The `data` you send should have form of: `{ key1: data1, key2: data2 }`. Are you sure it is like that?

Comment: There was only data, but now I think it has the right form: var data = ko.toJSON("name: "+ this.name())  and I changed req.queryParams("name"); but it didn't help

Comment: The right format would be: `var data = { name: this.name() };`

Comment: Why do you do this "ko.toJSON("name : "+this.name())"? toJson is supposed to work directly with the vm but you're passing a string as parameter.